# XSLT with C# code

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, transformation

I have to transform some XMLs with XSLT. The XSLT commands look like this for example:

```
<Transformation>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
   <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.IO" />
    <![CDATA[
        #region Custom-Code
        public static string FileExists(string path)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
            return (fi.Exists && (fi.Length >0)).ToString();
        }
        #endregion
    ]]>
   </msxsl:script>
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" />
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Attachement">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="@mimetype='XPS'">
      <xsl:if test="(@type='MANUAL') and (@print='true') and (user:FileExists(File)='True')">
       <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
 </Transformation>
```

As you can see there is some C# code included.

Now my problem:
I am writing a Java application. Of course the standard Java classes are not able to process the C# code.

I found this tool from Microsoft:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714

I thougt this should work but you need MSXML 4.0 to run this utility.
It is not a problem for myself but I'm developing this application for a company and it would be great if there is a tool which does not have any dependencies.
Another problem is that I read somewhere, that this utility is not able to process this c# code too but I am not sure if they used version 1 or 2 of it.

Only XSLT 1.0 transformation are required, but if possible I would choose a tool that supports XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Java then there are XSLT 1.0 (Xalan, Saxon 6) and XSLT 2.0 (Saxon 9) processors that allow you to use the Java API, for instance to check whether a file exists. See http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/extensibility.html for instance for Saxon 6 or http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#java-namespace for Xalan or http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/functions for Saxon 9.

I don't see why MSXML would help, it is a COM software package done in C/C++ and does not support calling into C# nor into Java, it has an extension mechanism allowing to use JScript or VBScript.